# Why this simple code doesn't work? How to solve this?

Tags: xml, groovy

Groovy code:

```
def root = new XmlParser().parseText(new File("sample.xml").getText())
void row (def path,q)
    {
        q.path.each {
            println it.value()
        }
    }

row ("food.name",root)
```

The sample xml file link is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml).

Normally, `root.food.name.each{}` works. but in above shown code it is not working. It prints nothing.

**Update 1:**

Expected output:

```
[Belgian Waffles]
[Strawberry Belgian Waffles]
[Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles]
[French Toast]
[Homestyle Breakfast]
```

Comment: Can check the solution to see if that is helpful?

Comment: @Rao Thanks for your response. my actual expectation is to get the path `food.name` inside `void` as tim_yates tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split and walk the path using `inject`:

```
void row(path, node) {
    path.split('\\.').inject(node) { n, p -> n."$p" }.each {
        println it.value()
    }
}

def root = new XmlParser().parse('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml')

row('food.name', root)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.It prints output instead of reaching that node. It doesn't reach the expected output.

Comment: Sorry..split uses a regular expression, so the `.` needed escaping... try now :-)

Comment: If you just want the text of each name, use `text()` in place of `value()` :-)

Comment: started using  `tokenize`  instead of using `split`. now you made it also too. really helped.. Thanks man

Comment: No worries :-)  Good luck, and have fun! :-D

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that in the way you are trying it. `root.food.name.each{}` is not the same as `root."food.name".each{}` (there is not "food.name" but "food"). An alternative way get the same results for `root.food.name.each{}` is `root["food"]["name"].each{}`. In this way is more readable that you are accessing level by level of the xml.

Answer (score 0):

By calling

```
    q.path.each {
        println it.value()
    }
```

You **do not** use the `path` variable actually, you just try to get `path` element of the root node.

`root.food.name.each{}` is fine and clean I think.
Or you can use variable in a loop

```
path.split('.').each { q = q[it] }
q.each { println it.value() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same using below script to extract all the food names as shown below (follow inline comments):

```
//Parse from file
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File('simple.xml'))
//Get all food nodes
def foods = xml.'**'.findAll {it.name() == 'food'}
//Get food names
def foodNames = foods.collect{it.name.text()}
//Print them
foodNames.each {println it}
```

Of course, you can even achieve the same in one liner:

```
println xml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'food'}?.name*.text()
```